# What is the advantage of higher priced arduinos to cheaper ones?

Tags: arduino-mega, hardware

I just got an Arduino Mega ADK (which seems to be functional, based on my limited testing and knowledge) at a yard sale for under $5. I don't have any Arduino experience, but I'm into DIYing, so who not try it.

I noticed that this specific board has a noticeably higher price than the other models. That would be, comparing brandname models to others brandname models, OR offbrand to offbrand.

My question is, why would someone prefer the higher priced models over the more simple/cheaper ones? My guess would be power consumption, I/O, capabilities, or processing speed. But I think I heard that the processing speed of the slower boards is already enough to run most projects, or am I wrong?

Comment: why different cars, different computers, different phones, different houses ...

Comment: You are right in your guesses. The Mega specifically is often used for its many pins and for the 4 hardware serial interfaces. The Pro Micro is often used, because it has a native USB interface (can act as different USB devices) in contrast to the Uno, Nano and Mega. So the different boards have different capabilities, use different microcontrollers, have different forms, and are thus better for one purpose than for the other

Comment: People buy the board that does the job they want it to do and provides the support and reliability they need for their project.

Comment: the higher price of Mega ADK is because of ADK

Comment: Usually because they don't understand I2C or SPI and want to hook up mounds of the absolute cheapest parallel interface gear to the MCU without writing any code themselves.